# Unity 3d app crashing with message : Failure to initialize, your hardware does not support this application

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

An apk built directly from a Unity 3d project or from a Unity exported Android Studio project crashes on some new Android models with the following error:

> Failure to initialize, your hardware does not support this application.

Comment: I voted this question down because it is not in the proper format. If you break it up in a question and an answer (http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) it will be much more helpful to feature readers, and I'd be happy to retract the vote and upvote the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I faced this issue on the One m9, it may affect other devices as well, so I'm leaving this information here in case any one faces this rather odd problem.

If you set "install location" as "prefer external" for a Unity app (which is  the default setting) in player settings, it will crash on the HTC m9 and probably other ARM v8 devices with the following completely misleading message:

> Failure to initialize, your hardware does not support this application.

Even logcat leads you to believe its something to do with the Snapdragon 810 being ARM v8 and x64. However, All you need to do is set "install location" as "force internal" and voila!

Many thanks to "tedneffv" of the Unity forum. Original question link: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1200893/failure-to-initialize-your-hardware-does-not-suppo.html